# 2 USB - RS232 adapters both work correctly but voltages significantly out of spec? I'm confused

Tags: usb, rs232

I have 2 different USB to RS232 adapters; One is a high quality Edgeport adapter and the second is a cheap PL2303 - but both devices work correctly when attached to equipment.

The adapters are setup back to back NULL MODEM style. I am measuring with a USB oscilloscope.  The Oscilloscope is measuring negative voltages accurately – (I verified using a voltage divider and my multi-meter – dc coupling)

**Neither of the USB-rs232 devices generates negative voltages in spec –
For a Mark (1) one adapter generates -1.5 volts and the other is only -200mV!!**

For a SPACE(0) one adapter generates + 5V and the other +4.9 V

Can anyone suggest where I might have gone wrong or why they do in fact work? Thanks for any suggestions to investigate, info or advice! [image]

Comment: Which exact adapters they are, post a model number or link to product page with specs? Are you sure that the Edgeport adapter is in RS-232 mode, as at least the one I found was configurable to RS-422 and RS-485 modes too, which could easily explain why the negative voltages get clamped.

Comment: Thanks justme good lead. interesting never thought to check if it also does RS422 and RS485, but of course that makes sense - although it requires a second chip - which the PL2303 most likely won't have..hmm will investigate..

Comment: PL2303 does not have RS-232 either, it's purely an USB interface chip with logic level IO. So whatever RS-232/422/485 standard it uses, it is done with an external PHY. If the adapter has no PHY then it has logic level IO only, with TTL/CMOS levels of 5V/3.3V.

Answer (score 1):

The actual switching threshold for the original MC1489 line receiver, and for the (once?)-popular MAX232 receiver are both over 1 volt, so the low negative output voltages of your interfaces should not cause a problem.

I exepect that other RS-232 line receivers would tend to match the switching thresholds of the original MC1489.

Answer (score 0):

RS-232 has always been tolerant to drivers over a wide range of bipolar supplies and different receiver designs with bipolar and CMOS technology with and without hysteresis.

From my observations all the specs point to my conclusion that all RS-232 receivers were designed to be TTL voltage level compatible but with >=4k input impedances.  So the negative voltage is just extra voltage margin.  The TTL input threshold is between 1.0 and 1.3V or about 2 diode and/or Vbe drops.

I guarantee, you could make it work with series R + clamps limiting the voltage swing outside the above levels of <=0.8V to >=2V (mark to space), which is specified for TTL.

It means for short cables of RS-232, you could use TTL voltage levels.

Also every TTL generation of families including 74HCTxx has met this criteria as well and have a nominal threshold of 1.3V.

The reason that the large negative voltages  was that without attempting to match driver or receiver impedances to cable impedance and thus ringing on long cables and/or crosstalk on cable bundles required more voltage margin and they decided to make it symmetrical starting with +/+15V then later for notebooks with 3V logic using +/-3V.